# What is the relationship between the code of an Area Control Center (US) and associated Flight Information Region?

Tags: usa, airspace, notam

From the [wiki page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Area_Control_Center), what I understand is

> an Area Control Center (ACC), also known as a Center (or in some cases, en-route, as opposed to TRACON control), is a facility responsible for controlling aircraft en route in a particular volume of airspace (a Flight Information Region). In the United States, such a Center is referred to as an Air Route Traffic Control Center (ARTCC).

My question: *Is ARTCC code different from the ICAO-FIR code? Or are there anomalies?*

For example, here's a [NOTAM](http://tfr.faa.gov/save_pages/detail_7_8867.html) in the FAA site. AT the bottom, under the headline **Other Information**, the ARTCC code is given as ZDC. Can I safely assume that the ICAO-FIR code would be KZDC for that NOTAM?

Comment: Partial answer: ICAO members agree on FIR borders and which member has the responsibility of providing FIR services (information and alerting). FIR cover international (oceanic) areas too. Then ANSP (e.g. FAA in the US continental area, plus NY OCA) appointed by members provide services, which include information and alerting, but can, and most of time do, include more (e.g. separation). Often the FIR is split into airspace types (A, B, C..., but also UIR) to determine which services are provided. Apart East Coast, a single ARTCC handles a single FIR.

Answer (score 2):

KZDC is the FIR associated with the ZDC ARTCC.  Think of KZDC as the airspace itself (the flight information ***region***), and ZDC as the facility which services it.

Comment: Thanks. My question then becomes: If ZDC is the ARTCC code, will the related FIR code always be KZDC (In the United States)? Is there one to one mapping from ARTCC to FIR? Or Is it many-to-one/other way around?

Comment: Of the ARTCC's that have oceanic FIR's three use the same code for both, (ZAN/PAZA, ZHU/KZHU, ZMA/KZMA), but Oakland and New York centers each have two FIR codes. ZNY covers KZNY and KZWY (oceanic). ZOA covers KZOA and KZAK (oceanic).

Answer (score 1):

Most are the same, but the scheme falls apart outside CONUS:

| FIR | ARTCC | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KZAB | ZAB | Albuquerque |
| **PAZA** | **ZAN** | Anchorage |
| **PAZN** | **ZAN** | Anchorage Oceanic |
| KZTL | ZTL | Atlanta |
| KZBW | ZBW | Boston |
| KZAU | ZAU | Chicago |
| KZOB | ZOB | Cleveland |
| KZDV | ZDV | Denver |
| KZFW | ZFW | Fort Worth |
| **PGZU** | **ZUA** | Guam |
| **PHZH** | **ZHN** | Honolulu |
| KZHU | ZHU | Houston |
| KZID | ZID | Indianapolis |
| KZJX | ZJX | Jacksonville |
| KZKC | ZKC | Kansas City |
| KZLA | ZLA | Los Angeles |
| KZME | ZME | Memphis |
| KZMA | ZMA | Miami |
| KZMP | ZMP | Minneapolis |
| KZNY | ZNY | New York |
| **KZWY** | **ZNY** | New York Oceanic |
| KZOA | ZOA | Oakland |
| **KZAK** | **ZOA** | Oakland Oceanic |
| KZLC | ZLC | Salt Lake City |
| **TJZS** | **ZSU** | San Juan |
| KZSE | ZSE | Seattle |
| KZDC | ZDC | Washington |